# apt-get upgrade gives 'failed: Connection timed out', How to fix this?

Tags: apt

`apt-get upgrade` command giving error:

```
Connecting to archive.getdeb.net (archive.getdeb.net)|144.76.200.19|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
```

I gave the ping command, as follows ::

```
   ping archive.getdeb.net
```

And got the output ::

```
 PING archive.getdeb.net (144.76.200.19) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

But after that it is remaining idl.
and when I stopped the command using ctrl+c, It showed following ::

```
--- archive.getdeb.net ping statistics ---
 465 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 464041ms
```

Does that mean that, the server is down.

Comment: Can you ping the GetDeb server? If no, it just might be down atm.

Comment: I gave the ping command, as follows ::   ping archive.getdeb.net   And got the output >  PING archive.getdeb.net (144.76.200.19) 56(84) bytes of data.    But after that it is remaining idle. Can you tell me what does that mean?

Comment: I can ping GetDeb without problems. Try if it's working again.

Comment: In my case, I could not connect to `rs.archive.ubuntu.com`, so I just replaced all occurences of `rs.archive.ubuntu.com` with `us.archive.ubuntu.com` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` to comment out that particular archive if you think it is not going to come back online at some point.

from a terminal, enter

`gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

look for the line calling `archive.getdeb.net`, and place a `#` sign at the start of the line.  Save the file, and try a update again.

Comment: But I want to get connected.